# What is the value of $0 \choose 0$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

It can be 0 according to $0 \choose n$ and 1 according to $n \choose 0$.

Comment: $\frac{0!}{0!0!} = 1$, because $0!=1$ by definition.

Comment: 0! is 1, not 0 so it can't be 0.  ${0 \choose 0}= \frac {0!}{0! (0-0)!}=\frac {1}{1*1}=1$.  That is, if it's a legitimate expression at all, which it is.  I'll admit, it seems weird and arbitrary that 0! is 1 when intuitively it should be 0, but if you think about it, if it were 0, than n! would always be 0.  So it has to be 1 or nonsense.  1 makes sense as the number of ways to choose zero, really ought to be 1.

Comment: ${0 \choose n}$ is only $0$ because (usually) $n>0$. That doesn't give you any precedent for saying ${0 \choose 0} =0$. Better to look at ${n \choose n}$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Plugging straight into the factorial expression, you wind up with $1$. Combinatorically, I interpret this as "there is always one way to do nothing". Set-theoretically, you can interpret it as there being one function with codomain equal to the empty set, regardless of what the domain is.

Comment: Yeah I've always interpreted it the same way: there is one way to choose nothing from nothing.

Comment: The important thing to realize is that 0! =1 \ne 0.  It can not equal 0 or *everything* would fail.

Comment: "you can interpret it as there being one function with *codomain equal to the empty set*, regardless of what the domain is". IMHO, this is saying $\binom{n}{0}=1$ which includes $n=0$ case.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\binom n k$ is the number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set, you're asking about the number of empty subsets of the empty set.  There's exactly one, so $\binom00=1$.